# How to invoke global setup for all tests in swift package?

Tags: swift, macos, xctest, swift-package-manager

Having a swift package, I want to do some global configuration (basically configure logging for all tests) before starting tests. 
Surprisingly, this is easy on Linux where code can be added in `allTests`

```
public func allTests() -> [XCTestCaseEntry] {
    Log.logger = HeliumLogger(.debug)
    return [
        testCase(MyTests.allTests),
        // ...
    ]
```

but I have no idea how to do this on macOS. Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass `XCTest` and override `setUp`, which is called before tests run, as follows:

```
import XCTest
import LoggerAPI
import HeliumLogger

class LoggingTestCase: XCTestCase {

    override class func setUp() {
        Log.logger = HeliumLogger(.debug)
    }
}
```

You can then make your test classes inherit from `LoggingTestCase` instead of `XCTestCase`.

This should work on both macOS and Linux.